# Updating App without installing new APK instead update swf in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

How to update a application without installing new apk, any option like changing swf file and xml file,using adobe air as3.

Comment: I can't answer that detail (maybe later someone knows a trick), but generally I think not possible. Tell us what kind of change/update? Maybe there's a workaround (like web downloading a new U.I theme file or some extra game levels, extra data, etc).

Comment: AIR AS3 application has a right (means it doesn't require a permission) to read/write the **File.applicationStorageDirectory** location, so you can design your app so its main body is just an updater which checks and downloads (if necessary) the files from some remote location then loads the external SWF and runs it.